# Is this a Federal Pacific electrical panel, and should I replace it?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I was told I might have a Federal Pacific electrical panel, and if so I may need to replace it.  It’s hard to read, but it looks to me like it says Trumbull Electric (see photo).  Is this panel something I need to worry about?  My house was built in the 1950s.

[image: electrical panel][image: close up of logo]

Comment: Can you carefully remove the cover and get a picture of the breakers inside. From an oblique angle rather than straight on would be best, and be careful of energized wires/busses of course.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the house? How large is it? Is there other electrical work you might want to do (ex. 2-prong to 3-prong outlets)? Do you intend to upgrade any appliances to electric? @RetiredMasterElectrician has an answer below, but you may *want* to replace the panel to modernize your electrical and give yourself some future-proofing.

Comment: I think this might be worth contacting GE tech support over -- see if this panel can use modern THQL breakers safely...

Comment: Also, can you get a photo of the listing label on the loadcenter?

Comment: Last but not least, what do you have for a main panel or main disconnect?

Comment: To be honest, I don’t know about some of the thins you’re asking, and I’m not eager to take off the panel as I know very little about electrical work.  I know the house and electrical are old (true for anything less than twice my budget where I live), but “old yet functional” can stick around until I have the money to do something about it while “old and likely to burst into flame” is a different story

Comment: @Brendan -- what do you have for a way of turning all the power to the house off?  Also, there should be a label somewhere on the panel you posted a photo of that has the UL symbol on it and a bunch of text -- if it's still there, can you post a clear photo of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have good news...

Your panel is *not* one of the dreaded FPE firestarters.  Trumbull panels appear to be ancestors of the modern-day GE loadcenter line, although I have not yet been able to ascertain if your panel is forward-compatible with modern GE (THQL) breakers.

### and bad news

However, these old Trumbull Electric panels *do* have a design defect: the upper row of breakers is "upside down"!  In other words, you have to flip breaker handles in the upper row *down* to turn them *on* and *up* to turn them *off*, which violates NEC 240.81:

> **240.81 Indicating.** Circuit breakers shall clearly indicate
>   whether they are in the open "off" or closed "on" position.
>
> Where circuit breaker handles are operated vertically
>   rather than rotationally or horizontally, the "up" position of
>   the handle shall be the "on" position.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a Federal Panel. It is a Trumble Panel built in the 1940's bought buy GE. Some say that's the reason GE breakers start with a T (TED THQ etc.)

Should you replace it? Yes, its a 1940's panel, but beware there could be a whole lot of things wrong with your service than just that panel. For example do you have a main fuse or breaker ahead of your panel? How is it grounded? ETC.